# How to publish web app in azure marketplace with "contact me" publishing option

Tags: azure, azure-marketplace

My application is a PaaS solution. But i want to publish it in Azure Marketplace for Marketing and get leads. And since marketplace is for only SaaS apps, i want to publish my web app in Azure Marketplace with a "Contact Me" publishing option.

1. Do i have to create a VM/Solution Template for this just like its mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace-publishing/marketplace-publishing-getting-started), even if i want it to publish as "Contact Me".
2. What are the steps i have to follow to publish it as "Contact Me"
   publishing option?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can definitely publish your web app with a contact me option. All you need to do is create a new "SaaS App" on cloudpartner.azure.com and then select "Listing" on the Technical Info.

Make sure to add your lead info on the Storefront details page!